# style attribute not being displayed using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to fetch **all** images of a particular manga chapter from online-manga sites using only the first page link.

I have successfully retrieved the total page number and the src of the first page, **for example**: if supplied with this link "http://www.mangapanda.com/feng-shen-ji/1/1" the output will be:

Total page :  49

Title : Feng Shen Ji 1

ImageURL : http://i15.mangapanda.com/feng-shen-ji/1/feng-shen-ji-2974919.jpg

what I want to do now is to fetch the src of the second page and then auto-increment to get the rest. The link to the second page is in the html as:

`<div id="prefetchimg" style="background-image: url("http://i34.mangapanda.com/feng-shen-ji/1/feng-shen-ji-2974921.jpg");"></div>`

but when I use jsoup as

```
String url = "http://www.mangapanda.com/feng-shen-ji/1";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
Elements div = doc.select("div");
for (Element divParse : div) {
if(divParse.id().equals("prefetchimg"))
System.out.println(divParse);}
```

I only get

```
<div id="prefetchimg"></div>
```

Instead of

```
<div id="prefetchimg" style="background-image: url("http://i34.mangapanda.com/feng-shen-ji/1/feng-shen-ji-2974921.jpg");"></div>
```

How do I get the style attribute?
    [image]

Comment: Actually, looking at HTML source of the page there isn't any style attribute. Are you sure about it?

Comment: I am using firebug to inspect the html elements. I got this "<div id="prefetchimg" style="background-image: url("http://i34.mangapanda.com/feng-shen-ji/1/feng-shen-ji-2974921.jpg");"></div>" by viewing the html of this link "http://www.mangapanda.com/feng-shen-ji/1" using firebug

Comment: Ok, in your case, your tag has been modified by a javascript function, so Jsoup can't see this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

[@eltabo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2165447/eltabo) said

> Ok, in your case, your tag has been modified by a javascript function, so Jsoup can't see this attribut

And this is true, JSoup is for Html page only. For Html with JS use for example [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: hmm...HtmlUnit seems to be something that I particularly don't want at this moment. Thanks to you and @eltabo, I am now using Jsoup to retrive <script> tags and doing some manual parsing to get what I need.