# java html parser multi page table

Tags: java, html, html-parser

i am using Jsoup as html parser to get all the details from the table in this [website](http://www.fifa.com/worldranking/rankingtable/index.html#). With the code below am only able to get the data on the first page only. Any advise?

> ```
>    public static void main(String[] args) {
>    String html = "http://www.fifa.com/worldranking/rankingtable/index.html#";
>    try {
>      Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();        
>      Elements tableElements = doc.select("table");
>
>      Elements tableHeaderEles = tableElements.select("thead tr th");
>      System.out.println("headers");
>      System.out.print("row");
>      for (int i = 0; i < tableHeaderEles.size(); i++) {
>         System.out.print(tableHeaderEles.get(i).text() + " | ");
>      }
>      System.out.println();
>
>      Elements tableRowElements = tableElements.select(":not(thead) tr");
>
>      for (int i = 0; i < tableRowElements.size(); i++) {
>         Element row = tableRowElements.get(i);
>         System.out.print("row");           
>         Elements rowItems = row.select("td");
>         for (int j = 0; j < rowItems.size(); j++)         
>         {                              
>            System.out.print(rowItems.get(j).text() + " | ");                              
>         }
>         System.out.println();
>      }
>
>   } catch (IOException e) {
>      e.printStackTrace();
>   }    }
> ```

Comment: I don't know if this could help...But try to read this answear:
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377942/style-attribute-not-being-displayed-using-jsoup>

Answer (score 1):

JSoup is a HTML parser, but looking at the website is using javascript to load the table. So you will need to click into it.

You could use HTMLUnit or Selenium for navigate and JSoup to parse the HTML.

I hope it helps.

Edit:

Looking better in the code of the page. I think that it could be useful :

http://www.fifa.com/worldranking/rankingtable/gender=m/rank=100/confederation=0/page=0/_ranking_table.html

I change the values of the URL, look that the rank u can increase (is the date of the ranking) and the important one would be the page. You could load all the ranking increasing the page parameter. Then just parsing it with JSoup would be enough.

For example the last ranking would be:
http://www.fifa.com/worldranking/rankingtable/gender=m/rank=237/confederation=0/page=1/_ranking_table.html

Then you could increase the parameter page=2, then 3, ... till 7

Cheers.